# Extract repetition from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table:

```
name       signature
XXX          DA
XXX          DB
XXX          DC
YYY          DA
YYY          DB
YYY          DC
XXX          DA
XXX          DE
CCC          AA
CCC          AB
```

As U can see I have repetition in table - name col is a name of the user. Signature is a code. I need to delete from this data frame and put to temp data frame all repetition but in special conditions.

If in data frame is repeated `name` AND `signature` -  All record with repeated `name` should be removed and put to another data frame.

So based on the data frame above, new_data should be:

```
   name       signature
    YYY          DA
    YYY          DB
    YYY          DC
    CCC          AA
    CCC          AB
```

And new data frame with repetition values:

```
   name       signature
    XXX          DA
    XXX          DB
    XXX          DC
    XXX          DA
    XXX          DE
```

What can I do it in best way? I looking for good advice in google and SO but not found nothing helped.

I just did it by `for loop` but the problem is a large size. My dataFrame has a 15 000 000 records. So I need to do it much faster. For sure pandas or python have a faster method which I did not find. Can someone help me with that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for get duplicated `name`s and filter original `DataFrame` by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for membership:

```
vals = df.loc[df.duplicated(['name','signature']), 'name'].unique()
mask = df['name'].isin(vals)

df1 = df[~mask]
df2 = df[mask]

print (df1)
  name signature
3  YYY        DA
4  YYY        DB
5  YYY        DC
8  CCC        AA
9  CCC        AB

print (df2)
  name signature
0  XXX        DA
1  XXX        DB
2  XXX        DC
6  XXX        DA
7  XXX        DE
```

Answer (score 1):

I've thought of a solution that might work, not sure if it is ideal but you can try to run it and see if it saves you time.

```
# Assuming df_val is your dataframe
print df_val
#create a column over name and signature to count over 
df_val["combined_index_column"] = df_val.apply(lambda x:x["name"]+","+x["signature"], axis=1)
#generate counts of unique rows
df_val["counter_index"] = df_val["combined_index_column"].apply(lambda x:df_val["combined_index_column"].tolist().count(x))
#generate list of names with duplicate rows
duplicate_name_list = df_val[df_val["counter_index"]>1]["name"].unique().tolist()
#get dataframe with repetition
dataframe_with_repetition = df_val[df_val["name"].isin(duplicate_name_list)][["name", "signature"]]
#get dataframe without repetition
dataframe_without_repetition = df_val[~df_val["name"].isin(duplicate_name_list)][["name", "signature"]]
print dataframe_with_repetition
print dataframe_without_repetition
```